# How to specify the Envoy proxy sidecar priorityClass with istioctl

Tags: istio

I am using `istioctl` to deploy Istio using the CRD below.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: IstioControlPlane
spec:
  profile: default
  values:
    global:
      priorityClassName: cluster-critical
```

However this also specifies the `cluster-critical` priority class for all injected Envoy sidecars and so every workload in the mesh would be `cluster-critical` which almost defeats the point of priority class. How can I specify this priority class for all Istio control plane components without manually specifying that value for each component?

In other words, is there a way to specify the priorityClass for just the sidecar? (It appears this value is only taken from the global setting).

Istio version: 1.4.4

Comment: The priorityClass is only applied at the Pod level, so it is not possible to set it per container (or just on the sidecar). Could you confirm it's added to sidecar? Could you share deployment, kubectl get pods where the priorityClass was changed? Are you looking for a way to limit the priorityClass to certain namespaces? You want to have priorityClassName for all the istio components when using ustioctl manifest apply, like galley, ingress gateway..., but not the injected deployments, am I correct?

Comment: I would like to apply the priorityClass to all Istio control plane components but not to the sidecar container because, as you say, this affects each Pod as a whole

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's not possible to do, unless you want to do it manually. If you use priorityClassName, eitgher in yaml or with istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.priorityClassName it applies to the deployments created by the Istio installation which contains pods without sidecar(citadel,sidecar injector) and with sidecar(galley,pilot,policy,telemetry).  It will affect pod with sidecar as a whole, like we both mentioned.

Comment: makes sense, I will just enable each one individually

Comment: I add this comment with some links as an answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The priorityClass is only applied at the [Pod level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#pod-priority) , so it is not possible to set it per container (or just on the sidecar).

As OP asked in comments

> I would like to apply the priorityClass to all Istio control plane components but not to the sidecar container because, as you say, this affects each Pod as a whole

As far as I'm concerned it's not possible to do, unless you want to do it manually.

If you use [priorityClassName](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/#KubernetesResourcesSpec)

---

either in yaml

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: IstioControlPlane
spec:
  profile: default
  values:
    global:
      priorityClassName: cluster-critical
```

---

**or**

---

with istioctl

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.priorityClassName
```

---

it applies to the deployments created by the Istio installation which contains pods without sidecar(citadel,sidecar injector) and with sidecar(galley,pilot,policy,telemetry). It will affect pod with sidecar as a whole, like we both mentioned in the comments.

Additionaly if you would like to limit the priorityClass to certain namespaces, this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#limit-priority-class-consumption-by-default) might be helpful.